# Creating a popup notification using Sencha 2 iphone toolkit

Tags: sencha-touch

I am exploring using Sencha 2 for making a mobile app - iphone first - using their packaging system. I need my app to be able to send notifications regardless of what app they are using - I could not find this in the Sencha API - is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and since I intend to package this up with PhoneGap it looks like this is what I will be using: http://www.easyapns.com/